# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while building android project

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, build-error

I have an open source android project : https://github.com/Ni3verma/Safe-Box

I worked and released it ~2years back and everything was working fine. Now I decided to build few more features. when I am trying to build this project again, it is failing with below error(on **master** branch):

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/nitin.verma1/Downloads/codebase/android/Safe-Box


> Configure project :app
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.\nIt will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nFor more information, see TBD.\nTo determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.","sources":[{}]}
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug
> Task :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest

> Task :app:copyGitHooks
Copied git hooks successfully.

> Task :app:installGitHooks SKIPPED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
33 actionable tasks: 33 executed
```

It used to work perfectly fine but I guess it may not be working because of some incompatibility issue with project and the new android studio that I am using now.

Can anyone help me here? there is no useful error message here :(

my android studio info:

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, built on April 19, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (222.4459.16)
    de.netnexus.camelcaseplugin (3.0.12)
    com.intellij.marketplace (222.4459.28)
    Key Promoter X (2022.3.1)
    com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.9)
    izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2023.2.7-ij)
```

below is my JDK settings now
[image]